# To change $USER in OS X's terminal

Tags: macos, unix, user

I would like an other way to change my current user than by GUI.

It would be great that if you can change the user as fast as you can your login shell by `chsh`.

**How can you change the user in OS X's terminal?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal Unix would do that with 'su' meaning 'super user'.

Something like

```
su - otherusername
```

GUI applications might or might not work, I don't know on OSX...

Answer (score 1):

`su` actually means “substitute user”.

Use `su -l USERNAME` to simulate a full shell logon that changes your variables and sets you to the user's home directory.

Type `man su` for other options.